# SQL SSRS 2016 Page Not working Remotely

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssrs-2016

The SSRS link works locally and works on some users laptops but not others. Now I have checked, and its not a firewall issue - can access on port 80 from the problematic laptops to the SSRS server. It is not an issue with the proxy as we all have the same proxy settings (I also disabled the proxy completely to test), still the same issue. Permissions are all set correctly, as the users where it works are all in the same active directory groups as the users where it doesn't work (plus it doesn't even load a login prompt which it should do).

I have also tried on multiple browsers, which all produce the same error.

see error below. Any help or pointers in the right direction to find the issue would be great

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Are you using IIS on that server? If so, are any websites in IIS accessible remotely?

Comment: Hi, no IIS used on the server